# vertical-align:bottom on child div

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm trying to get the hello world div to be at the bottom of the parent div but having no luck. Any ideas?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="float: left; padding-right: 0px; width: 98%; width: 170px; height: 490px; overflow: auto; text-align: center; border: 1px solid Black; padding: 0px; margin: auto;">
        <div style="width: 98%; margin: auto; border-bottom: 1px dotted Black; padding: 1px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblday" Text='<%# Bind("ShortDate") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div id="PanelDay" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5px;" runat="server"></div>
        <div id="Div2" style="text-align: left; vertical-align:bottom; margin-top: 5px;" runat="server">
            hello world
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Give your outer div `position: relative;`
2. Give the "Hello world" div `position: absolute; bottom: 5px;`

Here's a working example, with some of your styles cleaned up (I have yet to improve the formatting): http://jsfiddle.net/CqMqx/

Answer (score 1):

Vertical-align only works on elements that behave as table cells. There are two ways to achieve this. The first and most obvious is to use a table, though that wouldn't be best practice.

The other way is to use `display: table-cell`. [This Quirksmode article helps explain the different display attributes.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you:

```css
#footer {
    bottom: -100px; 
    position: absolute; 
    text-align: left; 
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vertical-align` property is for text (or images, or anything else that's inline). To get a block-level thing to be at the bottom, I think you'll to give the first div (the one that's floating left) a `position` of `relative`, and then give the "hello world" div the following CSS:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

There's more tweaking you'd have to do, but that's the general idea. (I say "I think" because I don't really work with ASP very much, and the context might not work with this solution.)